# Performance concern with static .json file getting called repeatedly from $http.get call with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm wondering about my decisions with performance and best practices as this looks like a code smell and a performance hit.

1. I have a static .json file    "Airports.json"
2. above json is ( ~200 lines of code with   just airline,alliance,carriedid)
3. angular filter is called in an ng-repeat loop to call the service several times per a few pages
4. service factory does this `http.get` EVERY filter to service call
5. call look like this    return $http.get(serviceBase + 'Airlines.json').then...
6. function in .then   return findAirport(results.data, code);
7. function loops through the json data that is fetched from $http.get
8. for (var i = 0; i < airLen; i++) {
               var item = airportList.airlines[i];
               if (item.carrierId == code) {
9. Is this horrible for performance?
10. What alternatives?

code architecture:

**html**

```
 {{ data.whatever | myfilter }}
```

**filter**

```
 .filter ..  calls service with the specific code  e.g. "DL"
```

**Service**

```
var airportCodeService = function ($http, $q) {
    var serviceBase = '../apps/temp/Api_Responses/',
        factory = {};

    factory.getAirlineFromCarrierId = function (code) {
        return $http.get(serviceBase + 'Airlines.json').then(function (results) {
            return findAirport(results.data, code);                
        });
    }

    function findAirport(airportList, code) {

        var airLen = airportList.airlines.length;
        var res = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < airLen; i++) {
            var item = airportList.airlines[i];
            if (item.carrierId == code) {
                res = item.airline;
                break;
            }

        }
        //console.log(res);
        return res;
    }
```

Seems that I should persist the json data instead of $http.get call each filter request etc.. ???

Comment: if... it's static... why are you requesting it more than once? ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the json is static, there's no reason to repeatedly request it. You're right that this will be awful for performance!

The most straightforward fix would be to request the data once when `airportCodeService` initializes, and save a reference to that promise.

```
var airportCodeService = function($http, $q) {
  var serviceBase = '../apps/temp/Api_Responses/',
    factory = {};

  //Request the data once at service startup
  var airlinePromise = $http.get(serviceBase + 'Airlines.json');

  factory.getAirlineFromCarrierId = function(code) {
    //Reuse the same promise - it won't make another request!
    return airlinePromise.then(function(results) {
      return findAirport(results.data, code);
    });
  }
}
```